# How does this algorithm work? What does this code mean?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to figure out what the code below means. I got it from freecodecamp.com and I am doing one of the challenges on there. The challenge is called "Seek and Destroy". I am just one of those people that has to understand what is going on in order for me to proceed, so can someone please explain to me how this code works and what is does from top to bottom?

```
function destroyer(arr) {


var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  return arr.filter(function(element){
    return args.indexOf(element) === -1;
  });
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

For example, what is the "element" parameter in the function for .filter() method? How does javascript know what "element" is in the first place? I have been asking people and reading descriptions of solutions, but every solution I read is very vague and is still confusing to me.

Side note: I already know the algorithm removes values from `arr`, but I just want to know how it does it.

Comment: Have you read any [documentation for `.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control)? That `element` is *not* a parameter of `.filter()`, it is a parameter of the anonymous function that is passed to `.filter()`. That function is called internally by `.filter()`, so it is `.filter()` that sets the value of `element` when it calls it.

Comment: What is `element` being set to in this case? @nnnnnn

Comment: Each element in the `arr` array in turn. Please read the `.filter()` documentation I linked to, study the examples there, and then if you still don't understand maybe somebody can explain further. As a further general hint, the `.slice.call(...)` line is converting all of the `destroyer()` function's arguments to an array so that they can be used with `.indexOf()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

This line takes all the arguments given in the function and places them into an array. In this case the value is `[[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3]`.

```
return arr.filter(function(element){
    ...
});
```

The [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control) function takes an anonymous function which can have three parameters: `element, index,` and `array`. In this case the function iterates through the array `arr` being `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`. For this function if `true` is returned the element is kept, if `false` is return the element is removed from the array.

```
return args.indexOf(element) === -1
```

Here we check if the array `args` has the element `element`. The [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method returns the index that the element is found, if it's not found `-1` is returned. What this means is if the element is not found it returns `true`, otherwise it will return `false` (removing it from the array) if it was found.

Basically the above statements means for each element in the array `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]` if it's found in `[2, 3]` then it's removed. It technically checks `[[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3]`, but the first check is against an array compared to an element which will always be `false` so it might as well be omitted.

Below are some brief comments stating what I mentioned above.

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  // An array of the arguments
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  // For every element in the array arr remove elements found in args
  return arr.filter(function(element){
    return args.indexOf(element) === -1;
  });
}
```